# Backup windows server 2008 fails - shadow copy

Tags: windows, backup, ntfs, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

I want to back up my Windows Server, but it fails when making shadow copy. I have seen that it only fails when I want to make a complete backup of the system (and not if I select only D or E drive).

I think that the problem is the empty 100 MB system drive that is not NTFS. Any ideas? There could be also another reason.

I use Windows backup tool; see error messages in tool and event log: screenshots

I do total system back up but I will also backup drives seperately in the future

[drive partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1bza.png)

[Backup tool error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqbvz.png)

[Event log error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2hLy.png)

Comment: You should edit your original post, not delete it and create a new one.

Comment: Just in case it's applicable or helpful to the issue, read over https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/970770/ntds-writer-postsnapshot-behavior-in-windows-server-2008-differs-from

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed this issue by starting backups without SQL server services.Just stop all SQL related services. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Further checks:

1. Check disk space.
2. Run the command `vssadmin list writers` in an elevated cmd and see if any
   writer is listed as having an error.
3. See if *Volume Shadow Copy Service* and *Shared Protection Point* added messages
   to the Windows application event log
   (they use VSS and SPP as their event-Source-identifier).

If you can't find any error, this might be a temporary timeout.
You may increase the timeout using regedit and navigating to:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\SPP
```

Create a new DWORD value named `CreateTimeout` and set its value.
For example, 2 minutes is 1200000 (2*60*1000) in decimal,
but set your own.
If the registry key `SPP` does not exist, then this advice does not apply.

Source: [Microsoft blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/asiasupp/2011/08/01/windows-server-backup-failed-to-backup-with-error-0x81000101/).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87334/discussion-on-answer-by-harrymc-backup-windows-server-2008-fails-shadow-copy).